# $PATH not saved as I login again

Tags: environment-variables, bashrc

When I make a change in my ~/.bash_profile file and I add such a variable as:

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"`

And after save and close, I need to reflect these changes in my $PATH variable. To do that, I'm doing

`source .bash_profile`.

When I echo my $PATH variable, the above added path is shown, but when I logout and login again, these changes aren't reflected..

Isn't it so that on each login, the .bash_profile gets reread?

Answer (score 3):

open `.bachrc` file and write it in it:

type `gedit ~/.bashrc` in terminal

copy and paste this line at the end of the file(one new line):

`PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"`

this way the path will be available every time you open terminal
besides this, you can also store some variables. for example, add `a="this a variable"` add the end of file. this variable will be available every time you open terminal. to check type `echo $a`

Answer (score 1):

You shoud write it in your `~/.bashrc` not in your `~/.bach_profile`, then it should work

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you may want to edit `~/.bashrc` instead. Just want to mention that if you want the modified PATH to be available also in the graphical environment, you should edit `~/.profile` rather than `~/.bashrc`.